# Dynamically Add <td> to tables using prototype/scriptaculous

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

i'm trying to add 's to a table dynamically with prototype/scriptaculous. I tried doing something like this...

```
function test(){

    $('td1').update('<td><img src="Images/Artists/2/111.jpg" height="444" style="border:1px solid #FFFFFF;" /></td><td><img src="Images/spacer.gif" width="10" /></td>');

}

    <div id="td1">
    <td><a href="#" onClick="test(); return false;"><img src="images/viewMore.gif" height="446" border="0" /></a></td>
    </div>
```

and when i click on the test() function, it replaces that  with other ones. This isn't working for some reason. Can you please give me a hand in figureing this out. Thanks all!!

Comment: Umm.. where's your `<table>` tag? You shouldn't have `<td>` without `<tr>` or `<table>`.

Comment: i wasn't showing that part of the code, but it's there. I tried using $('td1').innerHTML('') and $('td1').update('') but it won't replace the <td> inside of the <div> Any ideas?

Comment: well if you are doing `$('td1')`, and `td1` is a `<div>`, then you are still not using a `<table>` tag correctly.

Comment: here's the table...   <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin-top:10px;">
      <tr>
        <td><img src="Images/Artists/<%=id%>/<%=imgName%>" height="444" style="border:1px solid #FFFFFF;" /></td>
        <td><img src="Images/spacer.gif" width="10" /></td>
  <div id="td1">
        <td><a href="#" onClick="test(); return false;"><img src="images/viewMore.gif" height="446" border="0" /></a></td>
  </div>
      </tr>
  </table>

what i'm trying to do is dynamically replace the <td> with other content.

Comment: You can edit your question and add that table to it, would make it clearer what you want here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't use a `<div>` tag inside a table like that. You're going to have to either replace each `<td>` individually, or merge the two `<td>` tags into one `<td>` tag. For a simple but sloppy route, you could assign an ID to both `<td>` tags and replace them like this:

```
$('td1').update('<img src="Images/Artists/2/111.jpg" height="444" style="border:1px solid #FFFFFF;" />');
$('td2').update('<img src="Images/spacer.gif" width="10" />');
```

#### Update:

After you clarified your question in the comments, what you need to do is use `insert()` instead of `update()`.  `insert()` will append data to the end of the tag, whereas `update()` simply replaces it all.

Comment: The problem is that i have to try to figure out a way to add hundreds of more td's. What i'm trying to do is this... show 10 images... so <td>artists..</td><td>spacer</td>. At the end of the images, show a view more button, when it's clicked, i want to add more <td>'s to what's already there. The design of the table is only a 1 row table with hundreds of columns. I want to bring columns 10 at a time for loading's sake.

Comment: Scrap the table. This isn't what a table is meant to do. Just use `<div>` tags or `<span>`s, but the problem is you are using the wrong method... I'll update my answer.